# NTP is synced properly but still doesn't update the time?

Tags: time, ntp, ntpd

I wanted to test if `ntp` was working on my machine, so I set the time back 5 minutes and restarted ntp

```
$ sudo service ntp stop
$ sudo date -s "9:40 AM" # This time was 5 minutes ago
$ sudo service ntp start
$ ntpq -c lpeer # Check if sync to servers is working
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 hachi.paina.jp  .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 ts0.itsc.cuhk.e .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 ns.tx.primate.n .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 vpn.ipv4.cz     .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 europium.canoni .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
$ date
Mon Sep 23 09:40:50 MDT 2013
```

It appears that the `ntp` service can connect to its `ntp` servers just fine, but the clock on my machine still isn't updated - even after waiting 5 more minutes.

How do I get `ntp` to actually update my system clock?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
> .INIT.          16 u
> ```

That's *not* fine. You either queried the state to soon, or your `ntpd` can't connect to those servers at all. When it is synced, it should display IP addresses or host names in the `refid` column, and values like `2` or `3` in the `st` column.

The output of a working `ntpd` should look like this:

```
iserv ~ # ntpq -p     
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*char-ntp-pool.c .shm0.           1 u  162 1024  377   33.332   -5.160   1.225
+node3.mneisen.o 192.53.103.108   2 u  145 1024  377   30.391   -0.756   1.122
+38.101.77.21    64.113.32.5      2 u 1673 1024  336  184.925   20.728  18.911
-ntp0.sanctioned 131.188.3.221    2 u  563 1024  377   30.445  -50.495  18.027
```

Comment: Haha, good to know. Having not seen valid results on that screen before, it would have been nice if `ntp` was a bit more explicit in saying that something was wrong.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Try `ntpdate -d 0.debian.pool.ntp.org`, that should help you figure out if it's a firewall issue.